# Sleepimage deletion in Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, sleep-wake, graphics

I am not able to delete the sleep image. It currently runs on macOS Catalina. As root, when I try to delete the sleep image I get the message "Operation not permitted".

Can someone help answer how do I delete the sleep image?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: You delete the sleepimage @lhf, if it’s corrupted and you are having issues putting your Mac to or resuming it from sleep.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**    Under **macOS Catalina**, to remove the **sleepimage** *file* using **Terminal** while booted normally to your **Desktop**, use the following *command*:

```
sudo pmset hibernatemode 0
```

---

Tested under a **macOS Catalina** (10.15.6) system, without **FileVault**, the following was all that was necessary to remove the **sleepimage** *file*, typically located at: `/var/vm/sleepimage`

<sup>Note that this was done in a *normal mode boot* and booting to **macOS Recovery** and disabling **System Integrity Protection** was **not** needed. Even if booted to **macOS Recovery**, one **does not** need to disable **System Integrity Protection** in order to delete the **sleepimage** *file* from there.</sup>

Booted to my normal **Desktop**, in **Terminal** I ran the following *commands* to show it can be done as advertised:

```bash
~ % pmset -g | grep 'hibernatefile\|hibernatemode'
 hibernatemode        3
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
~ % ls /var/vm/
kernelcore  sleepimage
~ % sudo pmset hibernatemode 0
Password:
~ % ls /var/vm/               
kernelcore
~ %
```

- Setting **hibernatemode** to **0** automatically removed the **sleepimage** *file*.
- Setting **hibernatemode** back to **3** recreated the **sleepimage** *file*.

---

[image: Terminal]

---

**Notes:**

- The system I used did not have **FileVault** enabled, however, I doubt it would make any difference if it did.
- Tested under *normal mode boot* in **macOS High Sierra** after using `sudo pmset hibernatemode 0`, I had to manually delete the `sleepimage` *file* using: `sudo rm /var/vm/sleepimage`
- Did not test under **macOS Mojave**, however, one of the methods used under **macOS High Sierra** or **macOS Catalina** should work.

---

To remove the **sleepimage** *file* from **macOS Recovery** in **macOS Catalina 10.15.6**, without **FileVault**, I tested the following **without** disabling **System Integrity Protection**.

1. Booted to **macOS Recovery**
2. Opened **Terminal** from the **Utilities** *menu*.
3. Ran `diskutil list` to ascertain which *disk* was **APFS Volume VM**. It was: `disk1s4`
4. `mkdir /Volumes/VM`
5. `diskutil mount -mountPoint '/Volumes/VM' disk1s4`
6. `rm /Volumes/VM/sleepimage`
7. `diskutil unmount '/Volumes/VM'`
8. `reboot`

**Note:** This was included just to show doing the **SIP** *Dance* is not necessary under **macOS Catalina**, just remove it from a *normal mode boot*.

Comment: +1 Good answer.  Prior to Catalina I just went in and deleted the file manually.